# Why did this code make an error when drawing the function image? How to modify it?

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate

```
ClearAll@f;     
f[x_] := 2 Sin[x] - x - Log[x + 1]
Manipulate[Refresh[functions = Table[D[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, nMax, 1}];
  orders = 
   Table[D[f[x], {x, n}] // Inactivate // TraditionalForm // 
     ToString, {n, 0, nMax, 1}];
  labels = 
   MapThread[#1 <> " = " <> ToString[#2, TraditionalForm] &, {orders, 
     functions}];];
 Plot[functions, {x, 0, 3}, PlotLabels -> labels, ImageSize -> 700, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"f(x) = ", f[x]}]], {{nMax, 1, "Order"}, 1, 10, 1,
   PopupMenu}]
```

The above code ran with errors. How to modify it? I want to modify the code to make it universal. You can input any function and draw the corresponding function image and derivative image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) is more flexible for the display of multiple functions. With it, you can select any combinations of functions.

```
ClearAll@f;
f[x_] := 2 Sin[x] - x - Log[x + 1]

colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[11];

Manipulate[
 funcs = Sort@funcs;
 functions = If[# == 0, HoldForm@f[x],
     HoldForm@D[f[x], {x, #}]] & /@ funcs;
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   Tooltip[
      ReleaseHold@#,
      StringForm["``=``", Hold@#,
       Simplify@ReleaseHold@#]] & /@
    functions],
  {x, 0, 3},
  PlotStyle -> (colors[[funcs + 1]]),
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  PlotLabel ->
   StringForm["`` = ``", HoldForm@f[x], f[x]],
  PlotLegends -> functions],
 {{funcs, {0, 1, 2}, "Functions"},
  Prepend[Array[# -> HoldForm[Derivative[#][f][x]] &, 10],
   0 -> HoldForm[f[x]]],
  ControlType -> TogglerBar},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {funcs}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll["`*"];
f[x_] := (x - 1) E^x - x^2
xr = -10 <= x <= 10
gmax = Maximize[{f[x], xr}, x]
gmin = Minimize[{f[x], xr}, x]
lmax = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] < 0, xr}, x]
lmin = Solve[{D[f[x], x] == 0, D[f[x], {x, 2}] > 0, xr}, x]
Manipulate[Refresh[functions = Table[D[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, nMax, 1}];
  orders = 
   Table[D[f[x], {x, n}] // Inactivate // TraditionalForm // 
     ToString, {n, 0, nMax, 1}];
  labels = 
   MapThread[#1 <> " = " <> ToString[#2, TraditionalForm] &, {orders, 
     functions}];];
 Plot[{functions}, {x, -2, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {{Darker@Green, AbsolutePointSize[20], 
     Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]], AbsolutePointSize[16], White, 
     Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmax[[2]]]}, {Darker@Red, 
     AbsolutePointSize[20], Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]], 
     AbsolutePointSize[16], White, Point[{x, f[x]} /. gmin[[2]]]}, 
    AbsolutePointSize[8], Green, Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmin], Red, 
    Point[{x, f[x]} /. lmax]}, PlotLabels -> labels, ImageSize -> 700,
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"f(x) = ", f[x]}]], {{nMax, 1, "Order"}, 1, 10, 1,
   PopupMenu}]
```